# How to identify JPG/PNGS that are mosty text? (Windows/Mac/Linux prgram to do this?)

Tags: windows, macos, image-processing

Here's my problem:  A folder of 20,000 images- many of them are photographs but lots of them are basically scans of book text. I want to delete those.

Sorting by size helps a little, but since the images are of different resolutions some of the text ones are in fact bigger than the photo ones.

I'm thinking if I can find a program that can sort by color depth that might work? However a simply 'Number of colors' sort might not work because many of the photos i want to keep are drawings/black and white

Any ideas?

I have access to windows, mac, linux

Answer (score 0):

You could use a OCR Library for a Language of your choice. And if you get a String with more than 50 chars it's a textscan.

That's how I would try it.

Edit: 50 is just an example. You need to test what fits the best

Comment: This is a great idea. I am going to try https://code.google.com/p/python-tesseract/, even though I am no python programmer it seems like a good option to try. If this turns out to work I will mark it as answered

Comment: Did it work? Now I have a similar problem by finding Images with text =)

Answer (score 0):

Have you try to do something like Histogram analyse? Maybe it is not possible because of your black and white images, but they should have more different gray scales then that one with text. You could check which range of gray colors the images cover.